# How to display image from blob mysql in

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to display image from blob mysql data, but image not display, here the code :

```
$data = $this->Api_m->getData("calon", 'id_calon', $id)->result()[0]->gambar_calon;
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($data);
```

image type is png, and when i download from phpmyadmin is work. and because I want to show image in android so i cant use base64 image like this way:

```
src='data:image/jpeg;base64
```

Browser screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: an empty screenshot is not helpful - the saved data might be. Like what if the image is of a white square .. then it'd have worked. The encoding of the data is essentialy what we'd need to offer any solution.

Comment: Don't save files in a database.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540